# Disable encoding warning for templates in Netbeans 7.2

Tags: netbeans, encoding, smarty, typo3, fluid

I am frequently working with template files in  Netbeans 7.2:
In TYPO3, with HTML-based and Fluid templates; in OXID eSales, with Smarty templates.

If a template file contains a **charset variable** like follows, Netbeans utters a warning each time I open or save the file.
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; 
charset=[{$oView->getCharSet()}]">`

The warning:

> > ```
> > The encoding [{$oView->getCharSet()}] specified in meta tag of the 
> > document base.tpl is invalid. Do you want to load the file using 
> > UTF-8 encoding?
> >                                                             [Yes] [No]
> > ```

How can I turn this off?
(As a workaround, I usually replace `[{$oView->getCharSet()}]` with `utf-8`. But it's ugly.)

Answer (score 1):

HTML validation warnings can be configured to some extent using Netbeans `hints`. I haven't been able to verify this (as I don't have the latest version) but perhaps you can check the latest build if you IDE version doesn't provide an option to turn the warning off.

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Hints -> HTML Validator`

Build 7.1 onwards a new category called `Encoding` issues have been added to Netbeans. I think you would probably find an option to enable/disable the hint that controls this HTML encoding warning.

References:
[Wrong Encoding Warning on HTML-Files](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=197935#c11)
Not the exact bug you're facing but it makes references to related validation hints:

> There are some new hints options for HTML language in the editor options. There
>   are three new subcategories of Html Validator category - Encoding issues, Tags
>   matching issues and Others.

[image: HTML Hints in Netbeans]

Comment: Thanks Ravi. I disabled *all* warnings in the _HTML Validator_ tree. However, the error message persists (NB 7.2). I will file this over at netbeans.org, too. Maybe we have more luck with 7.3.

Comment: @Mateng Yes, with the use of templates becoming so commonplace now (I have some experience with FreeMarker and Velocity) it's high time they take it on priority. Please, do post your updates here!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on both 7.1 and 7.0.1 and got the same results. It seems that
changing charset encoding does not work until NetBeans is restarted.

```
1. Start NetBeans
2. Create a project by default
It means project encoding is set to "UTF-8" by default

3. Create a HTML file from File>New File... and Other>HTML File
The project encoding is set to UTF-8, so created file also should be UTF-8
encoding. -> OK


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

1. Modify "UTF-8" to "Shift_JIS" or other encoding like

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=EUC-JP">

   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Shift_JIS">
   ```

   Yellow line is displayed on the line and it complains

   Warning    Internal encoding declaration "euc-jp" disagrees with the
   actual encoding of the document ("utf-8"). From line 9, column 9; to line 9,
    column 76 (Rule Category: All Other)    newhtml.html
   /home/mkatakai/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication7/web/newhtml.html:9
2. Open propery of the file, it still says "UTF-8" (screenshot)
3. close the file and open it again, the warning is still displayed, project
   dialog of the file is still saying it's UTF-8
4. close the project and open it again, however, the warning is still
   displayed, project dialog of the file is still saying it's UTF-8
5. quit NetBeans and start it again, finally the warning disapper and project
   dialog says it's EUC-JP (screenshot)

Comment: Please, give the original author some credit by adding a reference. Don't just copy-paste. Original post at https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=206559 by `Masaki Katakai`.

Comment: You've misunderstood `Mateng`'s problem. What you've suggested automatically **changes** the file encoding to the one declared in content-type (EUC-JP in your case) but he wants to keep a template expression `$oView->getCharSet()` as its value which obviously won't work as it's not a valid encoding.